# Should I put that before a clause or not?

Tags: grammar, optional-that

I don't know which of these sentences is correct?

> There'd be a day we meet again.

or

> There'd be a day that we meet again.

I mean when should I use "that" before the clause?

Comment: "That" should not be there. This sounds just OK: "There'd be a day we meet again." The longer version would be: "There'd be a day _when_ we meet again."

Answer (score 1):

While the question didn't ask about it, "There'd" is short for "there would". While this is possible, "There  will" seems more likely. That would make the sentence

> There will be a day we meet again.

or

> There will be a day that we meet again.

Either of these is acceptable. I think the second is better, and I believe that it is more formally correct. However in speech or written dialog, the first form is not uncommon, and is quite acceptable. There is no significant difference in meaning by including or not including "that" here.